# Edit 2 labels from 1 text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

Good day! So here is my issue - I need to change 2 different labels from 1 text field. Tried simple if-else logic, but it didn't work in my case.

```
    func labelTextChanger() {

    if fromUserName.text == nil {
        fromUserName.text = textFileld.text
    } else  {
        replyToUserName.text = textFileld.text
    }
}
```

[ma case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdgQv.png)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change the text of 2 UILabels whenever you editing the UITextField? If so, you should use the "Editing Began" or "Editing Changed" IBAction linked with your storyboard file. Then, have the UILabel's value change to whatever the UITextField's text is.

```
@IBAction textFileIdEditingChanged {
    fromUsername.text = textFileId.text
    replyToUserName.text = textFileId.text
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but i need save fromUserName label text and edit replyToUserName text after textFileld editing

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
  func labelTextChanger() {

        if fromUserName.text?.characters.count > 0 {
            fromUserName.text = textFileld.text
        } else  {
            replyToUserName.text = textFileld.text
        }
    }
```

Because it will return nil only when it's not exists in memory. so, it can't be `nil`.

Comment: Thank You, but it didn't help. That logic fill only 2nd label (replyToUserName)

Comment: that means your `fromUserName` have some text so every time it called else part. AQnd from where are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `else` if you want to update both labels together.

```
if fromUserName.text == nil {
    fromUserName.text = textFileld.text
    replyToUserName.text = textFileld.text
}
```

---

A very broad example of an implementation you could use. Basically you should use the `UITextFieldDelegate`. When a user finishes editing the textfield a call to `textFieldDidEndEditing:` will be made and in this function you can update your labels.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var labelOne = UILabel()
    var labelTwo = UILabel()
    var myTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == myTextField {
            labelOne.text = textField.text
            labelTwo.text = textField.text
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about `UITextFieldDelegate` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/)

Comment: That logic didn't change any label!

Comment: Well that would be down to your condition (`fromUserName.text == nil`) not been met i.e. its `text` value is not returning nil. Without knowing your exact setup/what code you have, its hard to give you the correct condition to use.

Comment: I need edit second label after textField text is changed

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code that should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

it seems fromUserName.text is an empty string
so you should change to :

```
  func labelTextChanger() {

    if fromUserName.text != "" {
        fromUserName.text = textFileld.text
    } else  {
        replyToUserName.text = textFileld.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is right code for ma case:

```
var zalupa = Bool()


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (!zalupa) {
        fromLabel.text = textField.text
        zalupa = true
    } else {
        replyLabel.text = textField.text
        zalupa = false
    }
    return true
}
```